# "Of that time" vs "at that time"

Tags: adjuncts

The following is a sentence from the wikipedia page on [**Drexel Burnham Lambert**'s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drexel_Burnham_Lambert) early history.

> However, the company's ability to expand was limited by the structure of the investment banking industry **of that time**.

Why not **at that time** or **during that time**?

To be

> **of** *a* **time**

is to be in step with the happenings, styles, morals, and zeitgeist **at a particular point in time**.

> He was not **of** his time.
>   She was ahead **of** her time.

both mean the person was out of place during their life.

> the investment banking industry **of** that time.
>
> the investment banking industry **at** that time.
>   the investment banking industry **during** that time.

is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the company's ability to expand was limited by the structure of the investment banking industry of that time.

*Of that time* is by default understood to be an adjectival modifying *the investment banking industry*, implying fairly strongly that that industry is different now. If DBL later *was* able to expand, we would understand that this was due to a change in the industry.

*At that time* and *during that time* would by default be understood as temporal adjuncts, adverbials modifying the entire clause; it does not imply any subsequent change in the industry. If DBL later *was* able to expand, we would understand that this was due to a change in DBL itself.

Comment: Apologies spelling error Drexel Burnham Lambert (DBL)

Comment: @Peter I thought there was something wonky there!